# Functions exercise for $f(x) = \begin{cases} x \textrm{ if } x \le 3 \\ 11 - 2x \textrm{ if } 3 < x\end{cases}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Could you check on my answers? Any other observation is appreciated. I'm a bit new to the injective and surjective topics.

> Given $f : \{1,2,3,4,5\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ defined by
>
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x \textrm{ if } x \le 3 \\ 11 - 2x \textrm{ if } 3 < x\end{cases}$$
>
> Calculate:

$f(\{1,2,3\}) = \{1,2,3\}$

$f(\{3,4\}) = \{3\}$

$f^{-1}(\{1,2,3\}) = \{1,2,3\}$

$f^{-1}(\{4,5\}) = \{\}$

$f^{-1}(f(\{1,2,3\}))$ = $\{1,2,3\}$

> Is $f$ injective?

No. Observe that $f(1) = f(5) = 1$

> Is $f$ surjective?

No, because $5$ in the codomain has no preimage, right?

Comment: Take a look at $f^{-1}(\{1, 2, 3\})$ again.  It is asking what numbers in $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ get mapped into $\{1, 2, 3\}$.  Does $4$ get mapped into $\{1, 2, 3\}$?

Comment: Check your third answer.  Thus the fifth is also wrong. Beside this, very good work.

Comment: Oh snap. Thanks for the observations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting something just to get this off the unanswered list:

Check your third answer. Thus the fifth is also wrong. Beside this, very good work. –  Michael Hoppe

To prevent this from being converted to a comment:

Mama said there'll be days like this;
There'll be days like this, my mama said.
(Mama said. Mama said.)